# DESCRIBE command yields incoherent Display

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning to all.
Can anyone explain this incoherence?

1) What I get through the MySQL text client (check command in the first place):

[image: Shell Screenshot]

2) What I get through my WWW application:

[image: www/php Screenshot]

The php code is:

[image: php Code]

In other words, the NULL attribute will not display.

Following Dai's suggestion that php might "eat" an echo command, I changed line 21 to:

```
echo "<td width='80'>" . is_null( $row[4] ) ? "NULL" : $row[4] . "</td>";
```

The result is baffling (notice the jumbled offset after column 4 and the 5 'NULLs' above the table):

[image: jumbled rows]

THE QUESTION IS: Has anybody heard of any bug of the kind with PHP and, if so, can they tell me how to circumvent it? (Any other clue welcome, including about a gross mistake of mine.) Thank you.

Comment: Please replace images of text - with text. At least the php code. Using a screenshot means user cannot even copy, paste and edit the code in the question - because there isn't any code to be copied.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the `echo` call is failing, but PHP silenly eats the error rather than letting you know.

Use the `is_null` function to work-around this, like so:

```
echo "<td width='80'>" . is_null( $row[3] ) ? "NULL" : $row[3] . "</td>";
```

Repeat and modify as necessary.

Comment: Hello, Dai. Nothing doing, but you have brought up a difficult question. See what output I get when running your piece of code (row number was changed to 4): ![ChangedCode](http://bluevortex.zapto.org/DEBUGGING/ChangedCode.jpg). I suspect the devil lies with the row-offeset index…

Comment: @BriceCoustillas You have apparently forgot to copy the `<td width='80'>`/`</td>` tags into your code, evident from your actual code snippet in your question, and from the fact that the five `NULL` strings are visible _before_ the table.

Comment: Hello, @lanzz. No, I had _edited_ the snippet improperly for posting. The actual tested code line is: echo "<td width='80'>".is_null($row[4])?"NULL":$row[4]."</td>"; I also have removed all spaces that might cause parsing errors. Nothing doing. (Please note that Dai had wrongly written ($row[3]) for ($row[4])). Danke für ihre Hilfe.

Comment: @lanzz. My apologies if I hurted you —thought you were German.

Comment: You need to put `(is_null( $row[3] ) ? "NULL" : $row[3])` in parentheses, as the string concatenation has higher precedence than the ternary operator. Without the parentheses, that row is parsed as `echo ( "<td width='80'>" . is_null( $row[3] ) ) ? "NULL" : ( $row[3] . "</td>" )`, which is not what you're trying to accomplish. I'm not German, but no offense taken :)

Comment: Yes, it does work this way. Your explanation is just as simple as coherent: since we are dealing with an interpreter, a concept I am not conversant with (as opposed to compilers), it makes dam' good sense —three STARS. (Is there a way I can leave official feedback?)

Comment: @lanzz. See previous comment — I forgot to mention your name.